# Why am I getting a syntax error on my node production server build but not my local build?

Tags: node.js, express

I hope you can help me . i'm fairly new to node and am building my first node app.

I have built out an app in node.js. It works fine and as expected when running locally.
When trying to run it on our internal production server I get an error message. 
[image: error message in question]

It seems to take issue with the opening template literal tag. The file in question employs a simple module export function. I've stripped down the code a bit to make it easier to read. See below:

```js
    exports.templateModule = function(markup, edmData) {
    var template = `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
    </html>
    `;
    return template;
```

I'm using node version v6.11.0.

The production server is running on linux.

package.json file below incase it helps.

```
{
  "name": "template",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "A simple tempate test.",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^2.5.6",
    "ejs-lint": "^0.3.0",
    "express": "4.15.2",
    "glob": "^7.1.2",
    "node-dev": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-dev": "^3.1.3"
  }
}
```

I'll provide any other information you need if I can.

Any help or insight would be much appreciated.
 Thank you
 Moe

Comment: try like this :
`var template = '<!DOCTYPE html>    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body></body></html> ';`

Comment: what is Node.js version on your production server? type `node -v` in your server's terminal to find out.

Comment: @KayvanMazaheri. I think you're onto something. I believe the version is too old. My local node build is v6 but the production server is running node <v4.0. is it true that template literals only work with later versions of Node?

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty Thanks for your input. I believe the production server is running an early version of node and that is why template literals aren't working. Ideally I would like to avoid template strings as I want to have a lot of HTML markup and it still be legible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template strings were added in [NodeJS v4.0.0](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v4.0.0/).

> **Node.js v4.0.0** contains V8 v4.5, the same version of V8 shipping with the Chrome web browser today.
>   This brings with it many bonuses for Node.js users, most notably a raft of new ES6 features that are enabled by default including block scoping, classes, typed arrays (Node's Buffer is now backed by Uint8Array), generators, Promises, Symbols, ***template strings***, collections (Map, Set, etc.) and, new to V8 v4.5, arrow functions.

If you are using an older version of Node.js on your production server, please consider upgrading it to a more recent version.